# Sliding between multiple views using custom adapter

Tags: android

I am trying trying to create a gallery application that slides between three different xml layouts. Application looks quite wrong:

[image]

My XML files are:

```
linear.xml:
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="one"/>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="two"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="three"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>

table.xml:
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView android:text="What is your name?"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"/>
<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="@string/firstname"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <EditText android:text="John"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="@string/lastname"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <EditText android:text="Poe"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>

and the gallery.xml:
<Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gallery"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

My implementation of BaseAdapter:

```
public class LayoutsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public LayoutsAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                return R.layout.linear;
            case 1:
                return R.layout.table;
            case 2:
                return R.layout.relative;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate((Integer)getItem(i), null);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I am very new to android, so I am looking forward for your help.

Comment: ViewPageIndicator works with a ViewPager but is not part of the standard sdk or compatibility package. I would first implement as ViewPager with fragments and than use ViewPageIndicator if needed.

Comment: Thank you both. You mean, nothing can be done with my code?

Comment: I think that ViewPager/ViewPageIndicator has the advantage that it is supported at least by the compatibility library. And is part of SDK with 3.0+  So you would need to extensively test what you are doing to achieve this.  You can reuse your layouts etc because the ViewPager only takes care of the switching.  You still need to build out the individual pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use ViewPager. Checkout the following information on ViewPager:

http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/

Also consider that you might want to use Fragments in combination with ViewPager.

But ViewPager I think is what you are looking for.  In fact its much smoother than doing
you own layout stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use Jake Whartons [ViewPageIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)(or just a normal ViewPager):

Create a `Fragment` for every of your Layouts and set the layout to your Fragment with the `onCreateView()` method inside your fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);
    }
```

Now create a `FragmentPagerAdapter` there should be a method called `getItem()`. Switch the Position and set it to your Fragment:

```
    @Override public Fragment getItem ( int position){

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
                return fragment;

            case 1:
                TestFragment2 fragment2 = new TestFragment2();
                return fragment2;
        }

        return defaultFragment fragment3 = new defaultFragment();
        return fragment3;
    }
```

Now you should be able to swipe to your Layouts(Fragments) easily

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

Horizontal Pager
https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager

or

Real View Switcher 
http://marcreichelt.blogspot.com/2010/09/android-use-realviewswitcher-to-switch.html

Comment: What is the advantage of realviewswitcher? I am interested in this possibility but it seems less supported than pageviewer. Could you state its advantages. What it does better than PageViewer. Thanks.